# What is the significance of the results from experiments on gravitationally bound states of neutrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity

I have been reading some papers on the successful observation of quantized energy levels of neutrons in the gravitational field of earth (for example arXiv:hep-ph/0306198).
It seems they are clearly quantized and in agreement with the predictions form the Schrödinger equation with potential $$V=mgz$$
What is the significance of this result? I noticed the matter seems to be open to discussion. It does not witness any actual quantum behaviour of gravity (I suppose), and from a certain point of view it is not surprising that these low energy neutrons obey the Schrödinger equation. Are there any other views on this?

Comment: This question seems opinion-based and thus off-topic. My personal opinion is that the experiment is important but the result is unsurprising.  This is the effect of Newtonian gravity on quantum particles, not quantized gravity.